# Can I reference the name of a museum in an art book title?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

I am self publishing a printed book of drawings I've made at a natural sciences museum. Is it okay to use the name of the museum in the title as Drawing at (insert museum name)? I do plan to sell copies of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

There is no copyright in their name - it lacks the requisite creative effort.

There is trade mark in their name but you are using that trade mark in a way that is permitted - to identify them.